# In Windows 8, do I need to enable Hyper-V to get full performance from VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm tinkering with virtual machines on my new laptop, which is my first Windows 8 machine.  In the "Turn Windows features on or off" section of the Control Panel, I noticed that the "Hyper-V" options were all UNCHECKED.  Am I missing out on some virtualization performance in VirtualBox?  Or are they totally unrelated?  In other words, is VirtualBox taking full advantage of any virtualization features in my processor?  How can I check this?

My processor is Intel Core i7-3632QM

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper-V is an entirely different virtualization stack. The installation of VirtualBox installs VirtualBox's virtualization drivers. If hardware virtualization extensions are available, they will be used. Hyper-V is unrelated.